# Restricting POST request access to only from HTML Form

Tags: django

In my Django app, I have an html page with a button, "**Add user**". This add user button makes a post request to `/api/add-user`. How can I restrict it so that not anyone can just ping `/api/add-user` so that you can only do it from the form submission in the html page? Thanks!

Comment: `form` submission can be easily faked :), you better implement the authentication and authorisation mechanisms

Comment: @minglyu Thanks for the response!! How do you suggest I do this in Django?